# Shopify order shipping address id

Tags: shopify

Is there a way to retrieve the id of the shipping address per order? The shopify api returns the billing and shipping address and the billing address has an id field but the shipping address does not.

I need the shipping address id specifically, not just the address fields.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response :) When looking at the documentation: https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/order under "order properties" I can see everything being returned (which I am successfully able to retrieve via the api so that's not the issue.) and when I compare the shipping address to the billing address there's no id returned for the shipping address but there is for the billing address

Answer (score 1):

So I contacted Shopify support and this was their response:

At this time, there's no way to pull a shipping address ID from an order, rather the closest thing to your request would be to go through the Customer resource, retrieve the customer associated to a specific order and then grab that customers address using this endpoint:

```
GET /admin/customers/#{id}/addresses.json
```

I hope this helps anyone with the same query.